# awaitTermination blocks main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a following code :

```
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executorService.execute(() -> {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Here");
            }
    });

    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(5,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished");
```

After timeout - 5 milliseconds, thread stops writing message "Here" and main thread prints "Finished", but doesn't terminate and wait without any sense. What's the reason of this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

Your described behavior does not match my observation (on Windows). For me, the pool thread never stops writing "Here". Somewhere in the middle the main thread writes "Finished", but then the program just goes on printing "Here". The main thread has terminated. But the thread pool lives on.

Shutting down an executor service doesn't abort the threads. It just doesn't accept new tasks anymore and shuts down threads as they finish. But your task never finishes.

Comment: On my machine with Linux it prints about 100 times Here and then it prints once Finished and blocks forever.